# Python TypeError: expected a character buffer object, personal misunderstanding

Tags: python, unicode

i was stuck at this error during a long time :

```
 TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

i just understand what i has misunderstood, it is something about a difference between an unicode string and a 'simple' string, i have tried to use the above code with a "normal" string, while i had to pass a unicode one. So forgeting the simple "u" before the string was breaking execution :/ !!!

BTW the TypeError was very unclear to me, and is still.

please, can some explain me what i was missing and why a "simple" string is NOT a "a character buffer object" ?

you can reproduce with the code below (extracted and (c) from [here](http://perso.limsi.fr/pointal/dev%3atreetaggerwrapper): )

```
def maketransU(s1, s2, todel=u""):
    """Build translation table for use with unicode.translate().

    :param s1: string of characters to replace.
    :type s1: unicode
    :param s2: string of replacement characters (same order as in s1).
    :type s2: unicode
    :param todel: string of characters to remove.
    :type todel: unicode
    :return: translation table with character code -> character code.
    :rtype: dict
    """
    # We go unicode internally - ensure callers are ok with that.
    assert (isinstance(s1,unicode))
    assert (isinstance(s2,unicode))
    trans_tab = dict( zip( map(ord, s1), map(ord, s2) ) )
    trans_tab.update( (ord(c),None) for c in todel )
    return trans_tab

#BlankToSpace_table = string.maketrans (u"\r\n\t\v\f",u"     ")
BlankToSpace_table = maketransU (u"\r\n\t\v\f",u"     ")
def BlankToSpace(text) :
    """Replace blanks characters by realspaces.

    May be good to prepare for regular expressions & Co based on whitespaces.

    :param  text: the text to clean from blanks.
    :type  text: string
    :return: List of parts in their apparition order.
    :rtype: [ string ]
    """
    print text, type(text), len(text)
    try:
        out =  text.translate(BlankToSpace_table)
    except TypeError, e:
        raise
    return out

# for SO : the code below is just to reproduce what i did not understand
dummy = "Hello,\n, this is a \t dummy test!"
for s in (unicode(dummy), dummy):
    print repr(s)
    print repr(BlankToSpace(s))
```

producing :

```
u'Hello,\n, this is a \t dummy test!'
Hello,
, this is a      dummy test! <type 'unicode'> 32
u'Hello, , this is a   dummy test!'
'Hello,\n, this is a \t dummy test!'
Hello,
, this is a      dummy test! <type 'str'> 32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/treetaggerwrapper.error.py", line 44, in <module>
    print repr(BlankToSpace(s))
  File "C:/treetaggerwrapper.error.py", line 36, in BlankToSpace
    out =  text.translate(BlankToSpace_table)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that the `translate` method of a bytestring is different from the `translate` method of a unicode string. Here's the docstring of the non-unicode version:

> S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring
>   in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the
>   remaining characters have been mapped through the given
>   translation table, which must be a string of length 256.

And here's the unicode version:

> S.translate(table) -> unicode
>
> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
>   through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
>   Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.
>   Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
>   are deleted.

You can see that the non-unicode version is expecting "a string of length 256", whereas the non-unicode version is expecting a "mapping" (ie a dict). So the problem is not that your unicode string is a buffer object and the non-unicode one isn't - of course, both are buffers - but that one `translate` method is expecting such a buffer object and the other isn't.

Comment: thank you ! i was very very far from understanding this ! as i did not notice it was not the same object :/